# Ugly "Object moved" page when I try to apply to a position at Careers

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When I try to apply for [this position](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/72089/java-backend-developer-onebox-ticket-distribution) at Careers, I get redirected to an error page. The error page is just a message saying "Object moved to here" with a broken link (404) and a JavaScript empty alert.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click on "apply now"
2. On the popup, click on "Gmail". Note that this popup surprised me, it's the first time I have seen it.

Screenshots:

Job position

> [image: Job position]

Error page

> [image: Error page]

Comment: This does not repro for me with the steps listed.  Can you please try again?

Comment: @NickLarsen I tried again, this time on Ubuntu. The error page shows up, but no javascript alert and the default mail client (Thunderbird) shows up after a while.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I'll fire up some different scenarios and see what we can come up with.

Comment: Can you let us know what browser you're using there? Looks like some of the CSS is rendering incorrectly too (repeated Gmail icons).

Comment: Not to worry reproed in Firefox

Comment: @DeanWard Firefox 33.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, what it should be doing is open a new tab/window with a new gmail message having a pre-set fields.

When on its own, it works fine, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/scqcyqxj/

But some JavaScript voodoo on the Careers page cause it to fail, for me it's opening Outlook and probably you don't have Outlook thus you get the ugly error.

Not a fix, just hope to help clarify the problem.

Comment: True, I'm using Firefox on Windows without Outlook FWIW

Comment: @orique can you try and set gmail as the default email client? See [here](http://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/set-gmail-as-browser-default-email-client-ht), it might solve the issue for you until the bug is fixed. :)

Comment: Done, thanks for the help!

Comment: @ShadowWizard Just curious....why make this a CW post?

Comment: @Shokhet well, it's not a fix to the bug more like an extended comment so I feel it's wrong to gain rep from this.

Answer (score 4):

This was because our analytics hijacks the click before it has a chance to do its thing. When the analytics is done it redirects the caller back to the original URL.

For the webmail links it is supposed to return the URI to the provider, but instead it would attempt a redirect to the mailto: URI instead. Behavior varies across browsers - in some it cancels this redirect, in others it will act upon it; this is the behavior you were seeing in Firefox.

Anyway, I've pushed a fix that works for me on IE, Firefox, Safari and Chrome. It doesn't work on Lynx however :)

Comment: Thanks! I tried it again and can confirm the icons are now OK, the error page is gone... BUT a final glitch is that fields don't get populated (Firefox 33.1 on Windows 7, clicking on GMail link).

Comment: Thanks for verifying. Latest push resolves the last issue!

Comment: All ok now! :-)